# Mysqli multi query in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, foreach

I have to do a lot of insert in my DB, importing data from xml.
Now, **if I open and close the connection in the loop, the script works but crashes** for max connection number, and if I use the following code, it execute just one time the mysqli_multi_query.

> **I just need to know, how to maintain the connection to execute a new multi query in the loop.**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');
$mysqli =new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
foreach($xml->datas as $data) {
    $sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (hobby) values ('".$data->child74."');";
    $sql.="INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (pizza, spaghetti) values ('".$data->child55."', '".$data->child52."');";
    // a lot more insert...
    mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$sql);
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: you missed `"` or it is type ?

Comment: Why do you need `mysqli_multi_query` ?

Comment: typeof error........

Comment: In any case, your script will crash randomly as soon as data contains quotes or some other special chars. I suggest you drop your current PHP tutorial and learn the joy of prepared statements.

Comment: *Now, if I open and close the connection in the loop, the script works but crashes* obvious the script was gonna crush, with those many connections open

Comment: @bew78 I use mysqli_multi_query to create query using **$sql.=**

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it's just an example of my code, row by row I check and filter all the data.

Comment: Anyway, after vote down, I need some explanation to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. From the SQL point of view, data is just data. It does not need to be valid or get filtered. But you cannot mix data with code or the unexpected happens.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I presume who did it considered that it's impossible to diagnose an issue with some code that is not real. Perhaps you could edit the question, share real code (syntactically valid) and maybe define "crashes" with more detail. If "crash" means "query fails", you can (and should) fetch error messages from server.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you're still not answering my question. I have no data error, if I export the text of **$sql** var, it's valid, because I also imported it in my DB just for test.

Comment: Pardon? I didn't mean to answer your question. That's why I left **comments** instead of populating the **answer** box.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I just need to know, how to maintain the connection to execute a new multi query in the loop.

Comment: imo not good open and close the connection in the loop |
second better to use binding for insert to avoid errors | 
do not use $sql.= rather call $stmt->execute() several times for each insert |
show to us your timeout error

Comment: @bxN5 I have no error if I use the code you seen, It just execute one time. It's like that the  mysqli_multi_query needs to be cleared after executed

Comment: for mysqli_multi_query : Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon. Where is your semicolon separator?

Comment: @bxN5 sorry I forgot to place it in the code example. but as I said my problem has to be with a kind of reset of the mysqli_multi_query function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the multiple inserts you should be using **prepared statements**. This approach will solve all the problems you have at once. The only possible issue (related to possible non-optimal database settings) is solved by using a transaction.

The code below is using only single connection and as fast as it can be

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (hobby) values (?)");
$stmt1->bind_param("s",$hobby);

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (pizza, spaghetti) values (?,?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("ss", $pizza, $spaghetti);

$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
foreach($xml->order as $data) {
    $hobby = $data->child74;
    $pizza = $data->child55;
    $spaghetti = $data->child52;
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt2->execute();
}
$mysqli->commit();
$mysqli->close();
```

Prepared statements with a transaction make it civilized, secure and efficient solution.

Comment: I'm in love with your answer, but my problem is that there are around 60 insert query already done, with a lot of string conversion for each var... for some insert it will be ok, but imagine 50/60 insert with 10 columns each... I don't know

Comment: Don't know what? How to add 10 question marks to a query?

Comment: Yes, I'm on it ;) Thanks!

Comment: Any method to print the prepared query? A way to check it on screen without execution.

Comment: No, if you mean with values inserted. Values are going to server separately and never interfere with the query

Comment: I've tested the `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);` statement to check the Insert performance vs. Insert performace without `$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);`. To verify the duration, I've added a TIMESTAMP(6) row into a table and then executed an insert 3x for each statement with 25.000 rows and 6 columns. 

Time results with autocommit(FALSE): 
1:20; 1:40 and 1:41 Minutes

Time results without using autocommit: 
0:52; 1:52 and 1:36 Minutes

As a result, I could not identify any time advantages using autocommit(TRUE)

Comment: @Peter what is your database engine, myisam or innodb?

Comment: `@YourCommonSense` - MyISAM

Comment: @Peter then a transaction is not required

Comment: @YourCommonSense: do you think, InnoDB would Insert faster?

Comment: @Peter nope, it's irrelevant to the engine